# How to setup conference room that will either autojoin or one touch join a zoom or other video chat?

Tags: video, conferencing

I saw that zoom offers [zoom rooms](https://zoom.us/zoomrooms), but $50 a month per room means we probably won't be getting it soon or in every room.  Is there an easy way to set it up so that a conference room will either auto-join or maybe one touch on a tablet join a conference?  I think that would really help us work with remote teams better.  I was thinking maybe the tablet has Outlook and is logged in as an attendee or a resource that you invite to the conference.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Net admin here, we use Zoom at my work place for this exact purpose. We do not use Zoom Rooms either. If you're using zoom pro, you can use the same meeting ID each time, which allows for this functionality.

We use very simple batch scripts to accomplish this. Here's the syntax to start a meeting. Simply use the same meeting ID every time (remove the *'s). Configure this as a scheduled task for whenever you have your meetings.

```
start "" https://zoom.us/s/*meeting_ID*
```

The 's' in the above URL stands for "start meeting". If you want to do the same thing but for other users to JOIN the meeting, you can do this:

```
start "" https://zoom.us/j/*meeting_ID*
```

Again, configure this as a scheduled task on the other client machine to automatically join the meeting started in the first syntax.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I think this would work well for part of idea.  This would require managing the scheduled tasks and the meetings themselves in Outlook or whatever, separately, right?  So this would work best for recurring meetings.  Did you figure out a way to have it read from the calendar too or are you just relying on the scheduled task?  Maybe event creation, update and deletion for that resource can trigger some event to update the task scheduler?

Comment: That is correct, we use scheduled tasks for our weekly recurring meetings on Friday. I'm mainly a python dev and most of my duties constitute automating everything... though I have yet to fully automate the zoom meetings like you're talking about, as we have yet to have a need for that. 

As for random meetings we have a computer in the conference room with a batch script to start the meeting on the desktop, because we always use the same meeting ID, everyone knows how to join... we also have a simple batch script for joining.

Comment: Though like I said, it wouldn't be difficult to use any general purpose programming language to automate the starting/joining of meetings to integrate with outlook calendar events etc.... because all you're really doing is launching a URL on some event